# WYSIWYG with HTML source?

Tags: tinymce, html, wysiwyg, html-editor

I'm trying to switch from Drupal to WordPress, and I have lots of articles written in Drupal's WYSIWYG Editors, and stored like

```
<p>Hi, this is an article</p><p><img bla='bla'></img></p>
```

So I want to directly copy the source code and paste it into WordPress. I can do it by disabling the visual text editor. So it works for migrating existing articles in.

But what about writing new articles?

I couldn't find any wysiwyg editors that automatically insert `<p>` tags. I tried the [Ultimate TinyMCE](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/) plugin, but it only adds some buttons, does not change the situation.

**To summarize my problem:**

When I write

```
Article line 1
Article line 2
```

in the "Visual" Tab, I want to see

```
<p>Article line 1</p><p>Article line 2</p>
```

in the "Text" Tab.

But instead, I see exactly what I wrote, and this causes bad HTML output, when getting `$post->post_content;`

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the solution for this is the plugin called [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/).

Just install it, and go to Settings -> TinyMCE Advanced -> Check the box where it says `Stop removing the <p> and <br /> tags when saving and show them in the HTML editor`

Answer (score 0):

Why not automate the move from Drupal to WP? I think WP will fix some of the P tag issue during the upload. http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Drupal

If that isn't an option, I think WP is using br's instead of full new p. From the visual editor, I'd delete the copied break altogether and "enter" a new one.

Comment: As I see, wordpress does not even use <br>'s. It directly saves the article as plain text. like in notepad. Automating is not necessary, since I have 5-6 articles, I can copy paste them. But first I have to make sure that I can continue writing "migratable" content.